# null Object :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview

I am making a university app but does not getting what is the problem with my app, because it is not running. Can anyone help me to figure it out? This is the code. I am doing this in a navigation Bar Activity.

```
public class Sbbu_App extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivitySbbuAppBinding binding;

    ArrayList<Integer> mImageIds = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient,R.drawable.dr, R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient,
            R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient,R.drawable.dr, R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient,
            R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient,R.drawable.dr, R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.gradient

    ));
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GridView gridView = findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mImageIds,this)));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int item_pos =mImageIds.get(position);
            }
        });

     binding = ActivitySbbuAppBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarSbbuApp.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.ABOUT_SBBU, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.Academics, R.id.login, R.id.newsEvents)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_sbbu_app);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
    public void ShowDialougeBox(int item_pos){
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custome_dialog);

        TextView Image_name = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_Image_name);
        ImageView Image = dialog.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Button btn_Full = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_full);
        Button btn_Close = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);

        String title =getResources().getResourceName(item_pos);

        int index = title.indexOf("/");
        String name =title.substring(index+1,title.length());
        Image_name.setText(name);

        btn_Close.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }));
        btn_Full.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i =new Intent(Sbbu_App.this, FullView.class);
            i.putExtra("img_id",item_pos);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sbbu__app, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_sbbu_app);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'not running'? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `findViewById` before you have called `setContentView` or it will always return null. You got a NullPointerException because you called `setAdapter` on `gridView` but `gridView` was null.

You should move your call to `setContentView` up before anything involving views, and since you are using view binding, you don't need to call `findViewById` at all - just get the view from the binding class.

The binding class automatically calls `findViewById` when you inflate or bind it then saves all the views from your layout as class members so you don't have to do that manually.

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivitySbbuAppBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    binding.myGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(new ImageAdapter(mImageIds,this)));
```

Comment: Hey Tyler V, Thank You so much for responding that's so nice of you , But actually it is still not working , Can You please guide me more about this , actually I am a student and I don't have much grip on this , and I have to submit my project , Please Help me. I will be very Thank Full To You.

Comment: No, I cannot. First, StackOverflow is not an interactive debugging service. It is a place where you ask a specific question and get an answer to that question. Second, "it is still not working" tells me absolutely nothing. Chances are you have hit a new error with something else in your code. If you have, and you can ask a specific question about it that isn't already asked/answered here then you should ask a new question.